# Layout issues with Winforms present when built in Release mode, not in Debug mode or in the Designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I've run across a few layout issues over the years where when making GUIs with Winforms in C# where everything looks totally fine in Debug mode, but then I check it in and test our installed copy, and little things like labels not being positioned quite right (like the edge encroaches onto a nearby control) or other controls are misplaced by a few pixels. However, in the designer (both modes) and when running in Debug mode everything looks fine. Rather than having to build our entire solution in Release mode to make sure my layouts look fine, is there a reason that designer generated code is being built incorrectly between modes, and is there anything I can do to combat this?

We build against .NET 4.0, however, these issues have occurred when building for both .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5 SP1.

***EDIT*** Here is a comparison of the what the designer looks like and what happens when i run in release mode

**Designer/Running in Debug Mode**

[image: Designer/Running in Debug Mode]

**Running in Release Mode**

[image: Running in Release Mode]

Actually... now that I have  the side by side comparison, it looks like the font might be at fault, not the layout itself. I'm not sure what would cause a change between debug and release mode, or why the designer wouldn't show what would be rendered at runtime properly (unless there is a programatic change somewhere)

Comment: I don't think this is related to `Debub / Release`. It's most probably related to different resolutions in different machines. Does the `Release` build actually have the problem in your development box? winforms doesn't support many different resolutions (without resorting to some horrible hacks). That's why WPF was created to replace it =)

Comment: Yes, I just built in release mode a few seconds ago to test a change i made, there is a label encroaching on a button that does not show up when executing in Debug mode and does not show in the designer. I'll post a screenshot to show what is happening specifically

Comment: @HighCore Actually Winforms *does* support defferent resolutions, through `Fomr`'s [`AutoScaleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode.aspx) property (though not as good as WPF).